# QGuiApplication & QXmlQuery problems on qt5

Tags: qt5

I'm trying to use QtXmlPatterns module in order to parse an XML file.
Unfortunately using Qt5.1 on MacOsX 10.7&10.8 I found a problem I have not with Qt4.8.5.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QXmlQuery>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QXmlQuery qry;
    qry.setQuery("doc(\"file.xml\")");
    QStringList lst;
    qry.evaluateTo(&lst);
    qDebug() << lst;
    return 0;
}
```

this is the .pro I'm using.

```
QT += core gui xmlpatterns
TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG -= app_bundle
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

If I run a QCoreApplication everything works properly, instead if I switch on QGuiApplication (or a QApplication) this small program hangs forever on the evaluteTo function. It doesn't matter if file.xml exists or not.

On Windows and on Linux the same program run smoothly even if I use the QCoreApplication or the QGuiApplication or the QApplication.

I tried also to play a little with the QXmlQuery functions. If I call the setFocus function I got the same behaviour (with QCoreApplication everything it's ok, with QGuiApplication it hangs for ever on the setFocus function).

Suggestions?

Comment: Any reason why you do not use the QtCore parsers?

Comment: Unforturnately the code is already written and to rewrite it from scratch would be a long process. Anyway I don't know the "Qt core parsers". Can you, please, provide me some reference to them? Thanks a lot!

Comment: QXmlStreamReader/Writer. Unfortunately, QtXmlPatterns is unmaintained, has not got much improvement over the last few months or years (?). I would encourage you to rewrite it ASAP. I know it means some work, but it is better spent than using QtXmlPatterns in my opinion. You might end up spending more time with fixing bugs with that.